# When an African-American hero says 'enough already, you are asking too much of me'

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, pejorative-language

Is there **a phrase that expresses the rebellion of the "native" troops** protesting yet another battle against daunting odds when they have already proven themselves to be beyond compare...

Like Achilles supposedly sulking in his tent, but more positive in intent.

---

Recently  top athletes (such as Simone Biles and Naomi Osaka) are  saying that they are battling heat, humidity, and their own personal issues to drop out of an event. They are also battling the nasty comments made by high profile people such as...

> **Texas Deputy Attorney General Aaron Reitz** (R) [deleted a tweet calling gymnast Simone Biles a “national embarrassment”](https://thehill.com/homenews/state-watch/565414-texas-gop-deputy-attorney-general-deletes-simone-biles-tweet-apologizes) and issued an apology to the Olympian after the state’s attorney general came to her defense and criticized “a very inappropriate” tweet made by one of the office’s employees.

> **Charlie Kirk**, the founder of the right-wing youth group Turning Point USA, 
> , [calling her a “selfish sociopath” on his podcast.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2021/07/28/many-right-perceived-toughness-outweighs-patriotism/) “You know who has the gold medal? Russia! I have to go look at these four-foot-11 Russian Olympians chewing on their gold medals smirking at the Americans,” Kirk seethed, before claiming that America is **“raising a generation of weak people like Simone Biles.”** He also called her “immature” and a “shame to the country.” Kirk, who has previously said that “these Black athletes” in the NBA “are privileged brats,” accused Biles of teaching the “rest of the nation that when things get tough, you shatter into a million pieces.”

> **John Daniel Davidson** published a post titled “Sorry, Simone Biles, the Olympics Isn’t About You, It’s About Winning for America,” in which he seemingly **accused Biles of being too weak**. “Biles doesn’t suffer from a specific mental illness, at least not that we know of or that’s ever manifested itself before," Davidson wrote. “She wasn’t mentally tough when she needed to be.”

...and even the comments of hi-rep users here, who call them ...

> "professional athletes who fail to fulfill their potential."

---

Most of these objections seem to be focused on athletes of color.

No one should question the motives of these people; they are international ***models of emulation for children of color around the world...***

Many criticisms of these heroes are coming from "armchair warriors with bone spurs", "chicken hawks", and others of their ilk.

In defense of these atletes, is there a phrase that expresses the idea...

### "I have done the best I can; that is far far more than most mortals could do"?

---

EDIT

See [Hamburger Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Hamburger_Hill)

Comment: I've had all I can stands, and I can't stands no more! --Popeye.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. On one hand, it seems like you want something clever to tell the haters, and on the other you want the words to come from a "hero". But, if you look at all the inspirational quotes from athletic "heroes", you'd be hard pressed to find any of them saying essentially "I've done more than you schmucks ever could, so piss off." Heroes don't claim they should be free from criticism because they're better than "mere mortals". Great athletes typically are heartbroken when they can't compete.

Comment: @ColleenV I have edited and edited this question to satisfy BrE speakers whining about my quotes (now deleted) , but now I am fed up. I will delete the Q, in spite of the consequences

Comment: @Cascabel I'm sorry it's come to that, but this question just really coming across as a "help me clap back on Twitter". I can kind of see what you're looking for but it's not really a good fit for this format. Maybe the situation that inspired it is just too messy.

Comment: I don't do twitter. I don't have English speaking people to talk to. I have TV and you guys...

Comment: I'm gonna edit and  re-open this Q...

Answer (score 0):

"He who fights and runs away will live to fight another day."

Based on a quote attributed to Demosthenes, whose words are more accurately translated "A man that runs away may fight again." Versions are also found in Butler's *Hudibras* and in Goldsmith. ([A. Bent, comp.  Familiar Short Sayings of Great Men.  1887.](https://www.bartleby.com/344/137.html))

Comment: "When  a **hero** says...

Comment: Desmothenes, perhaps, but the English is 8-year old school playground.